# Django register

Tags: django, django-views

I am trying to get a user register in Django and then redirects him to his home page ie 'dashboard'. Though, it gets register but due to the authentication provided(`@login_required`), the user is not redirected to his home page. The user again has to submit his username and password to get login into the page.

Here is my **views.py**

```
def register(request):
    form = RegisterForm(request.POST or None)

    if(form.is_valid()):
        user = form.save()
        login(request,user)
        return redirect('/dashboard/')

    ctx = {
            'form' : form
    }

    return render_to_response('home/register.html',ctx, context_instance = RequestContext(request))


@login_required
def dashboard(request):
    HttpResponse("HELLO")
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `authenticate()` first, before calling `login()`.

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
if(form.is_valid()):
    form.save()
    new_user = authenticate(username=form.cleaned_data.get('username'), 
                            password= form.cleaned_data.get('password'))
    login(request,new_user)
    return redirect('/dashboard/')
```

From [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#how-to-log-a-user-in):

> When you’re manually logging a user in, you must call authenticate() before you call login(). authenticate() sets an attribute on the User noting which authentication backend successfully authenticated that user (see the backends documentation for details), and this information is needed later during the login process. An error will be raised if you try to login a user object retrieved from the database directly.

Comment: Well thanks. Looks Logical, but I'm getting `'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'backend'` error.
Any suggestions?

Comment: I tried with `login(self.request,newuser)` . but that doesnt works.

Comment: @user1162512 Can you tell me what is in `new_user` variable after calling `authenticate`.

Comment: The user is getting registered, but still its None. Any idea Why?

Comment: Do you use different databases for master and slave? If yes, then `form.save()` inserts the new user in table. And in next line when we try to fetch the new user (this time from slave database). There might be a little replication lag between the two, which is causing this.

Comment: No. I am not using any master slave databases. There is just one default database that I'm using,which iis postgres

Comment: Ok. Then please double check the parameters you are sending in the form and the ones you are sending to `authenticate()`. Also, are you using `user.is_active` condition anywhere?

Comment: Kindly close the question by [accepting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) the answer if it worked for you.

Comment: I have the same problem, and a suspicion that this is due to the User not being visible to login() yet. It tries to look up the User with User.objects.get(username=username) but even if the user was successfully saved earlier it always results in a User.DoesNotExist-exception. Hence user is set to None.